# New Building System in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have installed [masm32](http://www.masm32.com/) in `c:\masm32\`. Then, I have created a Build System in ST3:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "c:\\masm32\\bin\\build.bat \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\"",
    "file_patterns": "[\"*.asm\"]",
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "selector": "source.asm,source.ASM",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "encoding": "utf-8"
}
```

I can see my new system in the list under the "Build System" menu, but when opening an .asm file and trying to build, I can see the text `Line XX, ColumnXX; No Build System` at the bottom. It happens also if I explicitly select my Build System.

What is wrong in my configuration?

---

I have tried [this configuration](https://blog.izevg.ru/2015-05/pishem-na-assemblere-v-sublime-text-3) unsuccessfully:

```
{
    "shell": true,
    "cmd": ["ml", "/c", "/coff", "$file", "&&",
    "link", "/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS", "${file/\\.asm/\\.obj/}", "&&",
    "explorer.exe", "$file_path"],
    "selector": "source.asm"
}
```

Pressing Ctrl+B still says "No Build system".

Comment: what happens if you comment out the `"selector"`?

Comment: Same thing, nothing (apparently) changes

Comment: what do u get when pressing `ctrl alt shift p` on the file

Comment: change the build system automatically to urs

Comment: I finally got it running, and `Ctrl Alt Shft p` shows the expected `source.asm`. Maybe the problem was in `\"${file_path}\\\\${file_base_name}\""`, not sure. I modified and uninstall / reinstall several components until it worked